# How can I drag-select on Vuze?

Tags: bittorrent, vuze

I'm trying Vuze and I can't select multiple torrents (not all) clicking and dragging the mouse, like I do on uTorrent (as seen on the image). Searched on vuze forums and in general, but I couldn't find why. Any ideas? or you can't just drag-select?

[image: Drag-select]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need to use the 'usual' key/mouse click combinations to multi-select. I just added a suggestion to enable multi-selection dragging the mouse: http://vote.vuze.com/forums/170588-general/suggestions/6354292-drag-select-option-with-mouse